# Orchard CMS save MediaPickerField

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I'm developing a web app based on Orchard.

I'm coding a module that manages Staff Users, this users are ContentTypes(Staff_User) composed of UserPart and StaffUserPart (Custom part, defined in a migration) -> this part has a MediaPickerField.

This is the code in my controller to show the creation template of a staff users

```
 public ActionResult CreateStaff() {

        IContent staffUser = _contentManager.New("Staff_User");

        var model = _contentManager.BuildEditor(staffUser);

        return View((object)model);
    }
```

Ok, I have a template in EditorTemplates/Staff.cshtml . The MediaPicker field is attached by the the BuildEditor function (as a shape).

This is the Post controller:

```
 public ActionResult CreateStaffPost(FormCollection input) {

        IContent staffUser = _contentManager.New("Staff_User");

        //UserPart validation
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input["user.Email"]))
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "The Email field is required.");

        //Check if user already exits
        var oldUser = _contentManager.Query("User").Where<UserPartRecord>(x => x.Email == input["user.Email"])
            .List()
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (oldUser != null)
            ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "That email adress is already registered.");

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            var model = _contentManager.UpdateEditor(staffUser, this);
            return View(model);
        }

        StaffUserPart staff = staffUser.As<StaffUserPart>();
        staff.FirstName = input["FirstName"];
        staff.LastName = input["LastName"];
        staff.Location = input["Location"];
        staff.JobTitle = input["JobTitle"];
        staff.Summary = input["Summary"];
        staff.AreaOfExpertise = input["AreaOfExperience"];
        staff.Category = input["Category"];
        staff.Experience = input["Experience"];

        //Media picker field values
        var staffImageField = (MediaPickerField)staff.Fields.Single(x => x.Name == "Photo");
        //TODO Fix image save during creation
        staffImageField.Url = input["StaffUserPart.Photo.Url"];
        staffImageField.AlternateText = input["StaffUserPart.Photo.AlternateText"];
        staffImageField.Class = input["StaffUserPart.Photo.Class"];
        staffImageField.Style = input["StaffUserPart.Photo.Style"];
        staffImageField.Alignment = input["StaffUserPart.Photo.Alignment"];
        staffImageField.Width = String.IsNullOrEmpty(input["StaffUserPart.Photo.Width"]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(input["StaffUserPart.Photo.Width"]);
        staffImageField.Height = String.IsNullOrEmpty(input["StaffUserPart.Photo.Height"]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(input["StaffUserPart.Photo.Height"]);

        UserPart userPart = staffUser.As<UserPart>();
        userPart.UserName = input["user.Email"];
        userPart.Email = input["user.Email"];
        userPart.NormalizedUserName = input["user.Email"].ToLowerInvariant();
        userPart.Record.HashAlgorithm = "SHA1";
        userPart.RegistrationStatus = UserStatus.Approved;
        userPart.EmailStatus = UserStatus.Approved;

        //Set Password
        _membershipService.SetPassword(userPart.As<UserPart>(), input["password"]);

        //Create the StaffUser
        _contentManager.Create(staffUser);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**Question**

This works **but** the MediaPickerField doesn;t save the data. I use the debugger to see if the values from input["StaffUserPart.Photo"] and the values are there.

Any ideas?

Comment: The MediaPicker field is attached by the the BuildEditor function (as a shape) ... could you please show how to do this ?

Comment: As far as I understand, BuildEditor(ContentItem) assemble a shape with all the fields and parts that define that content item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing more work than you need to.  If you move your call to UpdateEditor, this method will do the work of putting posted values into your content.  You'll need to make sure you're implementing IUpdater.  Also, I added a dependency on ITransactionManager.  I'm hoping this will help catch something not getting put in the right spot.

```
public ActionResult CreateStaffPost(FormCollection input) {

    IContent staffUser = _contentManager.New("Staff_User");

    //Create the StaffUser
    _contentManager.Create(staffUser);

    //UserPart validation
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input["user.Email"]))
        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "The Email field is required.");

    //Check if user already exits
    var oldUser = _contentManager.Query("User").Where<UserPartRecord>(x => x.Email == input["user.Email"])
        .List()
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (oldUser != null)
        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "That email adress is already registered.");

    //This does all the work of hydrating your model
    var model = _contentManager.UpdateEditor(staffUser, this);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {   
        _transactionManager.Cancel();
        return View(model);
    }

    //Set Password
    _membershipService.SetPassword(userPart.As<UserPart>(), input["password"]);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```